# What is the use of to_ping and pinged column?

Tags: posts, table

Can anyone explain or show a reference for the use of `to_ping` and `pinged` column in the wp_posts table? It seems that my Googling skills have failed me.

I wanted to do an experiment using the `pinged` column to save the `term_id` of a term that is related to this post record.

I know that the proper way is to use custom field instead, but I wanted to reduce the mysql `inner join` in the WP_Query calls.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- `to_ping` is a list of URLs WordPress should send pingbacks to.
- `pinged` is a list of URLs WordPress has sent pingbacks to.

Do not use these fields for something else. They are parsed many times in core code (69 matches for `to_ping`); their format is fixed.

You cannot reduce the query load by using these fields, because *all* post meta fields are fetched in one rush per post. So it doesn’t matter if there is one more or less.